# Similar phrase to 'Let's have a chat...'

Tags: phrase-requests

I've found this in my friend's book -

> Let's have a chat so that we can set the balls rolling

Looks very professional but I couldn't find something similar to this one myself.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It sounds conversational and informal to me. Not what I’d describe as professional.  (Although in a professional setting an informal communication like that can be used to try to establish rapport.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A chat is a friendly conversation. "Let's have a chat" means the same as "Let's have a friendly conversation/Let's have a talk."

So, the whole sentence could be rephrased like this:

> Let's talk so that we can make it all start happening.

It's not clear what exactly should start happening, but you should know from the context, since you read the book.

By the way, the idiom is "[to set the *ball* (not balls) rolling](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/get-set-start-the-ball-rolling?q=get%2Fset%2Fstart%20the%20ball%20rolling)."